# FTP client command line put directory

Tags: command-line, ftp, client

Is there a command line FTP client where you can upload a whole directory?

Or does anyone know how to make a bat file that uses window's ftp client to upload a directory?

Any thing would be helpful, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try with [WinSCP](http://winscp.net/eng/index.php) (see [CLI docs](http://winscp.net/eng/docs/commandline)) or [NcFTP](http://www.ncftp.com/ncftp/)

Comment: NcFTP supports `mput -R *` to upload folders recursively. that's what I was looking for, thanks.

Comment: WinSCP uploads files recursively implicitly, use `put *` to upload just everything. See http://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_put

Answer (score 5):

Here's how you can do it in a batch file:

```
@ftp -i -s:"%~f0"&GOTO:EOF
open ftp.host.com
username
password
folder
mput "*.*"
disconnect
bye
```

replace the `"parameters"`(ftp.host.com, username, password, folder) with your own and save it as a `.bat`
Here's more information on [ftp scripts](http://www.dostips.com/DtTipsFtpBatchScript.php) in batch